# checkbox controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Hello this is my controller in laravel and I am not getting the problem here. It checks the file if I manually enter a dataset with the value of 1 but if I do it with the system it does not update the value and the box remains to 0 with unchecked box.

What I am trying to do is tick the box if the user tick it and keep the box ticked until he ticks it off plus update the database value too. Thank you in advance

```
public function tickoffUpload($id, $type, User $user) {

    $uploads = $this->upload->get($id);

    // if($this->request->isMethod('get')) {
    //      if($user->can('untick', $uploads)) {
    //           $uploads = $this->upload = 0;
    //      } else {
    //           return $uploads = $this->upload = 1;
    //      }
    //  }

     if($this->request->isMethod('get')) {
        if($type == 0) {
             $uploads = $this->upload = 1;
        } else if($type == 1){
            $uploads = $this->upload = 0;
            }
     }

    if(isset($_POST["uploaded"]) && !empty($_POST["uploaded"])) {

        $uploads->uploaded = $this->request->uploaded;
        $uploads->save(); 
    }

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is coming from this line: `$uploads = $this->upload = 1;`, you are assigning a value to $uploads which is an object not the variable, so you should instead do something like this: `$uploads->variable_to_update = $this->upload = 1;`. <variable_to_update> should be replaced with the corresponding variable like you did in `$uploads->uploaded = $this->request->uploaded;`

Comment: its still not working ... it's not updating the value in the database it's still 0 when I click on checkbox to and it remains untick with the database value of 0. This is what I did 

`$uploads->uploaded = $this->upload = 1;` because uploaded is the value that assigns 0 and 1 from the view 

my View.php

`<input type="checkbox" onclick="window.location.href='/tickedoff/{{ $upload['id'] }}/{{ ($upload['uploaded'] == 1 ? '1' : '0') }}'" 
                     name="uploaded" value = "1" required {{ ($upload['uploaded'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '') }}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted this out. I was not getting the requesting value from the form as you can see here `$uploads->uploaded = $this->upload = 1;` so here is the updated code which I did and worked.

```
public function tickoffUpload($id, $type, User $user) {

    $uploads = $this->upload->get($id); //gets upload id

     //   requesting uploaded value either 0 or 1
     if($this->request->isMethod('get')) {
        if($type == 0) {
            $uploads->uploaded = $this->request->upload = 1;
        } else if($type == 1) {
            $uploads->uploaded = $this->request->upload = 0;
            }
     }

    $uploads->save();   //  saving the value in database

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Thank you `d3r1ck` for the help though ... :)